# are JSON schemas allowed to have custom fields?

Tags: jsonschema

```
  language: {
    type: "array",
    items: {
      type: "string",
      enum: ["en", "es"],
    },
    ui_display: {"end": "English", "es": "Spanish"},
  }
```

This is a JSON schema for an array. the "ui_display" field is obviously not a recognized property. Will anything break if I include it?

Comment: It is a reconized property. It is an object. https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
   "type": "string",
   "enum": ["en", "es"]
  },
  "ui_display": {
   "end": "English",
   "es": "Spanish"
  }
 }

Comment: What something are you using? I know for example Connexion will break with this, so definitely something will break..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a python dict/javascript object/whatever, so you can add properties as much as you like.

However, a lot of different things use JSON Schema. Some will be fine with this others will break I would think.

I know for example [Connexion](https://github.com/spec-first/connexion) using [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/specification/) will break, so there's at least one case which will break.

That being said, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41020586/5272567) (did you even google this before posting the question?) you can extend JSON Schema.